# Change Label content with IsMouseOver on checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers

Hei,

Im creating a button what has a checkbox on top of it. Now when user hovers over the checkbox with a mouse i would like to change the text on the button.

Here's what i have currently:

```
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,136,12" Name="btnRefresh" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Click="btnRefresh_Click">
        <Grid Width="111">
            <CheckBox  Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="cbAutoRefresh" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Auto Refresh" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
            <Label Name="btnLabel" Margin="32,-4,25,-4">Refresh</Label>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

But like this it changes the content of the checkbox, how can i change the `btnLabel` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're just modifing the style of the ComboBox, thats why the Trigger just changes the Content of your ComboBox.

To listen to other controls properties in a Trigger, you can use Databinding like so:

```
<Label Name="btnLabel" Margin="32,-4,25,-4">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=comboBoxName, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"
                     <Setter Property="Content" Value="Refresh"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=comboBoxName, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"
                     <Setter Property="Content" Value="Auto Refresh"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>

</Label>
```

Comment: This is giving me error: `Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Text'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.`